# data not set using .set on Firebase

Tags: firebase

First question here,

I am trying to follow the startup guide on the Firebase, but as I am trying to click the send button, the data is not transferred to the data server.

Here is the code:

```js
var yjDataRef = new Firebase('https://yjyc-signup.firebaseio.com/');
var name = document.getElementById('name');
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');
nameRef = yjDataRef.child('nameRef');
        
submitBtn.addEventListener('click' function() {
    nameRef.set(name: 'name');
});
```

I have called all of them but still, the data does not transferred to the data center.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a comma after 'click'.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: still no luck, I changed it a little bit to  <script>
        var yjDataRef = new Firebase('https://yjyc-signup.firebaseio.com');
        var name = document.getElementById('name');
        var email = document.getElementById('email');
        var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');
        nameRef = yjDataRef.child('nameRef');
        
        submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        nameRef.set(name.value);
            name.value = '';
        });